# Can not configure wil6210 QCA9005 to AP mode "master"

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

I have wil6210 installed on ubuntu 14.04 as well as 15.04. The firmware is correct for wifi mode. All devices listed proper from terminal with lspci. iw list displays all device info for both devices properly. I try iw wlan1 mode master and it returns invalid argument. It returns the same for: iw wlan1 mode ap, iw wlan1 mode AP.

`iwconfig wlan1 mode master` returns not allowed or denied. What am I missing to get this card in ap "master" mode?

UPDATE

I tried the following at the terminal and was successful in putting the card into monitor mode: iwconfig wlan1 mode 6 I then got lucky and used the following at the terminal to get it back into managed: iwconfig wlan1 mode 2 Still looking for AP mode.......

Comment: How about `sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode master`?

Comment: Yep I tried that as well with the same result. I have also tried as root....

Comment: Do you have this working? On 60 Ghz? And where did you get the firmware or cards with the correct firmware? I've been trying this for some time now and ordered all the cards I could find online but all have 60ghz wifi disabled by Dell or https://www.qualcomm.com/